# Apache HTTPS URL Rewrite

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've just started playing with Linux and Apache and got stuck on this.

I have this rewrite rule working fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ /myserver/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myserver/ [R]
```

How can I redirect to `https` applying these same rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[On the Apache wiki:](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

If I understand your question correctly, you can implement this in your specific example.

Note that it is recommended to use a redirect inside your non-secure VirtualHost to your secure VirtualHost.